# Integrating Object Detection jupyter notebook with android studio Kotlin app

Tags: android, kotlin, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I have an object model in my jupiter notebook which uses opencv. This model is trained using custom dataset and YOLOv3. Now I want to integrate this model with my android Kotlin application. I have create basic pages for the kotlin app.

**The idea of the appliccation**

The app must be opened with a camera detect the object with the camera. Then the user will click on next which will redirect to another activity in the app.

**The object detection**

I have the  YOLOV3_custom.cfg and yolov3_custom.weights. In my jupyter notebook I open the webcam of my computer using  `cv2. VideoCapture(0)`.
This will detect the image with bounding boxes.

**The Kotlin app**

I have created a basic kotlin app with different activities.

**What needs to be done**
The kotlin application must open a camera and detect the object. After detection on clicking next it must go to the next activity. Please help in doing this step. I know there is a need for tensorflow but I do not have an idea for using it.

Answer (score 0):

step1: convert .weights to .tflite file
step2: Deploy .tflite to kotlin app

resource1:[step1](https://medium.com/tfug-mumbai-weekly/yolov3-to-tensorflow-lite-conversion-4602cec5c239)

resource2: [step2](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/tflite-object-detection-android#0)

But this still gives the following error:

```
org.tensorflow.codelabs.objectdetection E/TaskJniUtils: Error getting native address of native library: task_vision_jni
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error occurred when initializing ObjectDetector: Mobile SSD models are expected to have exactly 4 outputs, found 1
```

Unable to figure out how to solve this but these resource are really helpful in building a basic structure.